# Does groovy.sql.Sql.firstRow Closes Connection After Execution?

Tags: grails, groovy

In MyService I have the following:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class MyService {
  Sql groovySql

  def serviceMethod(){
    groovySql.firstRow("some query.....")
  }
}
```

In resources.groovy groovySql inject as follows:

```
groovySql(groovy.sql.Sql, ref('dataSource'))
```

This is a Grails 2.4.5 application. Now, the question is when `serviceMethod` is called, is the connection closed automatically?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/subprojects/groovy-sql/src/main/java/groovy/sql/Sql.java#L1709

Comment: @dmahapatro it only releases ResultSet. It doesn't actually closes connection.

Comment: @dmahapatro, You are right, `protected final ResultSet execute() throws SQLException` does release connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every method in `Sql` creates and releases resources if necessary.

> Under the covers the facade hides away details associated with getting
>   connections, constructing and configuring statements, interacting with
>   the connection, closing resources and logging errors.

If you create a `Sql` with a `DataSource`, it will get a new connection every time, and close it at the end of the operation.

> If we are using a DataSource and we haven't enabled statement caching,
>   then strictly speaking the final close() method isn't required - as
>   all connection handling is performed transparently on our behalf;
>   however, it doesn't hurt to have it there as it will return silently
>   in that case.

Comment: There are some cases that only ResultSet is being released. What do you mean by "releases resources if necessary". In what case it NOT necessary?

Comment: "There are some cases that only ResultSet is being released", which one? the connection is allocated for each methods and closed after that. however, most datasource are pooling datasource: They don't close the underlying datasource when Sql releases it.

Comment: This method: `public List<GroovyRowResult> rows(String sql, int offset, int maxRows, Closure metaClosure) throws SQLException`. But then I found that `protected final ResultSet execute() throws SQLException` will release connection as well. I will accept this answer.