# Should I close the groovy Sql in Grails service

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm using groovy Sql in a Grails project.

```
class MyService{
    def sessionFactory
    def method(){
        def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
        def query =...
        sql.rows(query,...)
        sql.close()
    }
}
```

I see a lot of examples online about groovy sql in grails. All of them are not including the `sql.close()` in their code.

I'm wondering why. Is it because Grails has already managed the session connection after a service method is executed?
If so can you give me some evidence(or resources) I can refer to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does groovy.sql.Sql.firstRow Closes Connection After Execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588115/does-groovy-sql-sql-firstrow-closes-connection-after-execution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessary. Please refer to [Does groovy.sql.Sql.firstRow Closes Connection After Execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588115/does-groovy-sql-sql-firstrow-closes-connection-after-execution)

Take a look at the link provided in the comments of the question by dmahapatro https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/subprojects/groovy-sql/src/main/java/groovy/sql/Sql.java#L1709